Cookies can only be modified in a Server Action or Route Handler
In the backend, I send the access token and refresh token in the response by jwt, and in the nextjs 14 app router, I save them in the cookie after the user login.
Now, the problem I have is when the user's access token expires, I generate a new token for him by refreshing the token, but I encounter the same error.
this is my refreshAccessToken function for get a new access toke:
    'use server'


import {cookies} from "next/headers";
import {isTokenExpiringSoon} from "@/app/utils/utils";
import {modifiedCookie} from "@/app/_actions/modifiedCookie";


export async function refreshAccessToken(refreshToken) {
    console.log("Attempting to refresh access token...");

    if (!refreshToken) {
        console.error('Refresh token not found');
        throw new Error('Refresh token not found');
    }

    const refreshResponse = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/token/refresh/`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            refresh: refreshToken,
        }),
    });

    if (!refreshResponse.ok) {
        console.error('Failed to refresh token:', refreshResponse.statusText);
        throw new Error('Failed to refresh token');
    }
    console.log('working on it')

    const data = await refreshResponse.json();
    const newAccessToken = data.access;
    console.log(`newAccessToken in refresh: ${newAccessToken}`)

    modifiedCookie(newAccessToken)

    console.log("New access token set:", newAccessToken);
    return newAccessToken;
}

and this is my fetchUserData function for get user data:
    export async function fetchUserData() {
    const cookieStore = cookies();
    const accessToken = cookieStore.get('access_token')?.value;

    console.log("Current access token in fetch:", accessToken);

    if (isTokenExpiringSoon(accessToken)) {
        console.log("Access token is expiring soon, refreshing...");
        try {
            const refreshToken = cookieStore.get('refresh_token')?.value;
            console.log("Refresh Token:", refreshToken);
            await refreshAccessToken(refreshToken);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error refreshing access token:', error);
            throw new Error('Unable to refresh access token');
        }
    }

    const newAccessToken = cookieStore.get('access_token')?.value;
    console.log("New access token to use:", newAccessToken);

    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/user/user-profile/`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${newAccessToken}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
        console.error('Failed to fetch user profile:', response.statusText);
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch user profile');
    }

    const user = await response.json();
    console.log("Fetched user data:", user);
    return user;
}

After this i get this error:
Current access token in fetch: ey...
Access token is expiring soon, refreshing...
Refresh Token: ey...
Attempting to refresh access token...
working on it
newAccessToken in refresh: ey...
New access token set: ey...
New access token to use: ey...
tA [Error]: Cookies can only be modified in a Server Action or Route Handler. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies#cookiessetname-value-options
at Proxy.callable (/home/comiser/Desktop/tasteproject/frontend/tastecoffee/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:36:13455)
at modifiedCookie (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/_actions/modifiedCookie.js:14:61)
at refreshAccessToken (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/_actions/actions.js:41:80)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async fetchUserData (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/_actions/actions.js:54:13)
at async RootLayout (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/layout.js:38:16)
Failed to fetch user profile: Unauthorized
Error fetching user profile: Failed to fetch user profile
